# Spring Data Rest PagingAndSortingRepository AbstractMethodError (RepositoryFactorySupport)

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to buil an Rest Api using Spring Data Rest, after to change my pom.xml many times to find the compatible dependencies to my project, I have this problem now:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Once upon a time ...

I have a Java Config Web App, my JPAConfig has these annotations

```
@Configuration
//@EnableJpaRepositories("com.protect.inf.jpa.repositories")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig { ... }
```

See the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, if i don´t set the package name where are my Repositories class, the application starts fine, but when I make the request to the api, the response looks like this:

```
{
_links: {
    profile: {
        href: "http://localhost:8080/protect-inf-01/api/profile"
        }-
    }-
}
```

It doesn´t expose my Repos url. My Repos classes looks like this

```
@RestResource(path = "users", rel = "users")
public interface UsuariosRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Usuarios, Integer>{
    Usuarios findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Then ...

When I set the package name to the `@EnableRepositories` annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.protect.inf.jpa.repositories")` the applications start fails with this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'cuentasRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I think that is a dependencies problem in my Maven, i'm not really sure.
Here is my pom.xm

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>protect-inf-01</groupId>
    <artifactId>protect-inf-01</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>protect-inf-01 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SERVLET -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>protect-inf-01</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my `WebAppInitializer` class

```
package com.protect.inf.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{JPAConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

This is my `WebConfiguration` class

```
package com.protect.inf.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration{
    @Override
      public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
        config.setBasePath("/api");
        return config;
      }
}
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

***SOLVED***
Deleting the `spring-data-commons` and changing the `spring-data-jpa` version to 1.9.0.RELEASE like @peeskillet said now works fine!

Comment the spring-data-commons dependency

```
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.11.0.RC1</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
```

Change the spring-data-jpa version

```
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks peeskillet!

Comment: See what happens if you get rid of `spring-data-commons` and change `spring-data-jpa` version to 1.9.0.RELEASE

Comment: Great! ***Ha funcionado perfecto!!!*** Can you explain me why?  `spring-data-jpa` includes  `spring-data-commons`? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get rid of `spring-data-commons` and change `spring-data-jpa` version to `1.9.0.RELEASE`.

Both `spring-data-rest-webmvc` and `spring-data-jpa` already depend on `spring-data-commons`. But you need to make sure that they both depend on the same version. `s-d-rest-webmvc-2.4.0` depends on `s-d-commons-1.11.0` while `s-d-jpa-1.8.2` depends on `s-d-commons-1.10.2`. And that's the difference. `s-d-jpa-1.9.0` depends on `s-d-commons-1.11.0`.